# Creating Repeater that is hidden but remains in the markup for Javascript use

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visibility

Right now I have two repeaters: 1 will be shown when the page loads, the other one I want to remain hidden until a link "Add Stuff" has been clicked.  When this is clicked I would ideally like to use javascript to make this second repeater visibile.

The problem is that in order for the javascript to act on the second repeater it needs to be present in the page.  Simply setting the:

`<asp:Repeater Visible="false"....>`

will leave the repeater out of the markup entirely.

Is there a way to make this repeater visible when I click my button using javascript?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="display: none;">
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ...>
        ...
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add style="display:none" to the element.

To do this in code:

```
repeater.Attributes["display"] = "none";
```

Edit:

I did not know the repeater class does not have an Attributes collection.  In that case wrap the repeater with an element you can toggle.  You only need the runat attribute if you want to access the element on the server

```
<div id="container" style="display: none" runat="server">
  <asp:Repeater ...>
</div>
```

Comment: I have done this in the past for other controls. The reason I ask this is that repeaters do not contain a definition for Attributes, meaning you cannot use this.

Comment: I didn't realize that.  Then you would want to to as Darin suggested and wrap it in an element that you can toggle.